# When do we have finite fourth moment

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk

Let's consider a random walk $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ starting from the origin, with the following conditions:

finite range, symmetric distribution, irreducibility (with respect to the state space), finite second moment and mean $0$, aperiodicity.

The fact that the distribution is symmetric, implies that the all odd moments are $0$. I would need finite fourth moment. Does it is possible to recover it from these assumptions?

Comment: Well, each $S_n$ has finite fourth moment if and only if the common distribution of the increments $X_k$ has. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did not really... I would like to know if the above assumptions on the chain, would imply $E[\mid X_1\mid^4]<\infty$

Comment: @Did I think I see it now. The key point should be the fact that the chain is of finite range which would mean that in this case all possible increment of the chain are finite. And this should imply that all moments of $X_i$ are finite. Is it correct?

Comment: You seem to be changing the question since the "finite range" condition is more stringent than the "finite fourth moment" one. Regarding the "finite fourth moment" question, please read carefully my first comment.